# Render to FBO gives unexpected results

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl-es

I have an Android plugin in Unity which will do some native rendering using OpenGL ES.

I have simplified the code to this, and it successfully reproduces the problem:

```
       GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);

    //Draw texture to framebuffer
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_MVPMatrix, 1, false, matrix, 0);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, verticesBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_texCoord);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(a_texCoord, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, uvBuffer);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);

    GLES20.glFinish();
    GLES20.glFlush();
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

It is working fine when I am forcing Unity to use only OpenGL ES20, but if using OpenGL ES30, I get unexpected results and the input array given here:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, verticesBuffer);
```

Is ignored and the given quad is drawn in a different shape. No matter what I change the input coordinates to, I still get the same odd shape.

I am not an OpenGL coder, so I cannot find the issue. Am I missing to set some states here?

Comment: What is `verticesBuffer`? The name of an OpenGL buffer, or a Java buffer object? Client side vertex arrays are marked as deprecated in ES 3.0. They should still work, though.

Comment: verticesBuffer is of type FloatBuffer, and contains the coordinates for the vertexes in the quad.

Comment: Ok. As I said, this should still be supported for backwards compatibility with ES 2.0, even though it's a deprecated feature in ES 3.0. But you're probably better off using VBOs anyway.

Comment: Are you correctly querying the binding locations for the attributes and uniforms (e.g. how are you getting the location values of `u_MVPMatrix`, `a_Position`, etc)? I could imagine an ES 3.0 compiler may have different binding offsets due to extra built-in symbols it has to allocate (which may share binding table identifiers with applciation symbols).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Reto Koradi in the comments, client side vertex arrays are deprecated in ES 3.0. And when switching to VBOs it works. Not sure why, but assume it is related to some unknown OpenGL state left after Unity.